# Big O and Asymptotic Notation

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, chebyshev-function

So I am currently working in the Apostol Book "Introduction to Analytic Number Theory", and am attempting to prove one of the major results regarding the prime number theorem. Specifically I am trying to show that given:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\pi(x)\log x}{x} = 1$$
show that:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\vartheta (x)}{x} = 1$$
What I have done so far is this: We know for $x > 2$ that:
$$\vartheta (x) = \pi (x) \log x + \int_{2}^{x}\frac{\pi(t)}{ t}dt$$
This a result derived previously in the book. So we must show:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\pi(x)\log x +\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\pi(t)}{t}dt}{x} = 1$$
Clearly, it suffices to show that:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x}\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\pi(t)}{ t}dt = 0
$$
Apostol then discusses a bound on the integrand. Specifically, states that:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\pi(x)\log x}{x} = 1
\implies \frac{\pi(t)}{t} = \mathcal{O} \left(\frac{1}{\log t} \right)
$$
for $t>2$. At first, I was unsure as to where this result comes from, but then I realized one could get it by dividing the $\log x$ from both sides of the limit definition. However, it still does not make sense as to what the result means/wether it is rigorous or not. I guess the question I am asking is, what is the connection between big $\mathcal{O}$ notation and asymptotic notation (limit of a quotient)?

Comment: Did you simply look for a definition of [Big-O asymptotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)? It should allay all your doubts...

Comment: He does not need something to raise doubts.  He needs something to allay doubts.

Comment: @GEdgar Indeed. Thanks.

Comment: @Did Looking back at the definition I feel quite stupid for asking this. It becomes fairly obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(x)\log x}{x} = 1,\tag{1}
$$
and the claim is that
$$
\frac{\pi(t)}{t} = \mathcal O\left(\frac{1}{\log t}\right)\qquad\text{as $t\to\infty$,}
$$
which is to say that there exists $B>0$ and $M>0$ such that $\pi(t)/t \le B/\log t$ for all $t>M$. Clearly the claim is true if and only if
$$
\frac{\pi(t)\log t}{t} \le B \tag{2}
$$
for all $t$ sufficiently large. Since you are given $(1)$, you have $(2)$ since eventually the quotient $\frac{\pi(t)\log t}{t}$ is $\le 2$, say.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite rigorous:

All you need is that the stated limit implies that $\pi(x)\log x/x<M$ for $x$ large enough. ($M$ can be any number greater than $1$.)
From this you get $\pi(x)/x<M/\log x$ for $x$ large enough, and that is precisely the meaning of the big $\mathcal{O}$ notation.